# Select multiple div text inside another div using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a div structure which is similar to this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="input">ABC</div>
    <div class="input">DEF</div>
</div>
```

Now I need to pick up the HTML text inside the `box` class.

Using:

```
$('.box').html();
```

returns `<div class="input">ABC</div><div class="input">DEF</div>`.

To return just text from the `inputs` div, I tried

```
$('.box div.input').html();
```

but this gives me the html content only for the first div. How do I get the content of the second and subsequent divs?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `.text()` method.

Comment: For the second one -> `$('.box div.input:eq(1)').html();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `text()` method in jQuery

```
$('.box').text();
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/V4pBR/)

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Is it possible for me to split the text of the two divs using a ';'?

Comment: are you want output as `ABC;DEF`

Comment: Yes either that or ABC, DEF. Anything that will split the the text of each div by a separator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using css selector.

First div element:

`$(".box div:eq(0)").html();`

And second div element:

`$(".box div:eq(1)").html();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .text(), using .html() will select the first div

```
$('.box div.input').text()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3YME/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `.text()` method.
http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
$('.box div').text()
```

As the names suggest, the `.html()` method is for working with html and the `.text()` method  is for working with text. When you call the latter it returns only the text content of the selected nodes without any markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.box div.input').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```